# TypeError: testing() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was having a weird error in my python code . I checked the other posts on SO for this problem but everyone else seemed to have some sort of mistake in the code which I could figure out. Am not able to identify this one.

This is the function call:

```
print "Desired Action: " , person.bestAction(indx)
```

And this is the definition of the method in an npc class of which person is an object.

```
def bestAction(self, position):
    if self.beingPassed:
        if self.protestCost() > self.waitCost():
            self.nextAction = "Protest"
    else:
        if self.passCost() > self.waitCost():
            if position != 0: 
                self.nextAction = "Pass"
```

And this gives me the following error:

```
File "main.py", line 91, in stepCounter
  if person.bestAction() == "Pass":
TypeError: bestAction() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I believe that self is an implicit parameter. So I should be giving only one parameter which I am passing to the function.

I am confused and I don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: Where is the rest of your class definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` is only an implicit parameter when the function is called as a method of an object.  The definition of `testing` is not contained in a `class Foo(object): ...` block, and `testing(2)` is not a method invocation, and so `self` will not be implicitly passed.

Comment: The function `foo()` has zero arguments, but `obj.foo()` has one argument - the object itself, which is what goes into `self` in the function declaration.

Comment: Thanks this helps a bit. But my actual code is a class definition and I do create an object of the class. I gave a single argument but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Yathi: Do you actually *use* the object of the class when calling `testing`?  Writing just `testing(2)` won't work; you have to write `object_of_class.testing(2)`.

Comment: @jwodder: I have changed the code in the question to a more complete form.

Comment: @Yathi: Could you update the error message as well so that we can see exactly what error the "complete" code is giving you?

Comment: @jwodder: I updated the error msg and now I also found the problem. I was calling the function in another place. Where I did not pass the parameter. And removing the self was causing an error in the first place. And I was confusing both! Stupid of me.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your doing it may be advisable to do the following:

```
class Tester(object):
    def testing(self,someint):
        print someint

tester = Tester()
tester.testing(2)
```